# Programmatically draw rect and line in Highcharts with zoom

Tags: javascript, highcharts, draw

I'm doing some programmatic drawing in Highcharts using [Highcharts.Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer) using `path()` and `rect()`. In the code below I have manually plotted the coordinates for the line and rect. In reality the are related to the main data series (dates with values).

**How can I programmatically draw something and make the zoom work?**

The main graph, with zoom:

```
    chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
```

The programmtic drawing:

```
 chart.renderer.rect(100, 110, 100, 100, 5)
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red',
            fill: 'transparent',
            zIndex: 3
        })
        .add();
  var path = [
    'M', 100, 100,
    'L', 130, 110,
    'L', 160, 105,
    'L', 190, 150,
    ];
  chart.renderer.path(path)
        .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'blue',
        zIndex: 4
      })
      .add();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8ro1b9m/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now you are not really using your chart values - you are drawing your rect and path independently from your series. You can connect your drawings with your chart using your point y and x values and Axis.toPixels() method: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.toPixels

```
$(function() {
  var addRect = function(chart) {
    $('.rect').remove();
    var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
      yAxis = chart.yAxis[0]
    chart.renderer.rect(xAxis.toPixels(1), 110, xAxis.toPixels(2) - xAxis.toPixels(1), 100, 5)
      .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red',
        fill: 'transparent',
        zIndex: 0
      }).addClass('rect')
      .add();
    chart.renderer.rect(0, 0, chart.plotLeft, chart.chartHeight + chart.plotTop, 5)
      .attr({
        fill: 'white',
        zIndex: 0
      }).addClass('rect')
      .add();
  };
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'x',
      events: {
        redraw: function() {
          addRect(this);
        },
        load: function() {
          addRect(this);
        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
  });
});
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/n8ro1b9m/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `series.data` values in your function by using:

```
chart.series[0].data[i].y
```

With `i` the number of the point in the series. 
Is that what you want to do ?