# drawing multi colored custom symbols in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to draw custom markers on a highchart at particular intervals.
I have managed to create a custom bar using the following javascript:

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.hline = 
    function(x, y, width, height) {
        return ['M',x-30 ,y + height / 2,'L',x+width+30,y + width / 2];
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jimmain/9gqca584/5/

My problem is that I need to also draw a **single pixel border around the pink box**.
I am using a stacked bar chart for the chart.

Ideally I would also like to **increase the padding underneath the bar** (between the bar and the x-axis) but I am not sure it can be independently increased.

[image]

It's not clear to me how I can use the renderer to change color. I could just draw one black box, and then another smaller inset pink box on top, but I am not clear on how to change colors in the SVG renderer.

Comment: For the padding underneath the bar you can use [`offset`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.offset) on the `yAxis` (yAxis since this is a bar chart). Here is an extreme example: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/9gqca584/7/

Comment: These might help you [drawing a custom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470174/programmatically-draw-rect-and-line-in-highcharts-with-zoom), [SVG path](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path)

Comment: Is this some kind of a bullet chart? For a bullet series, see details in [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/bullet-chart). The problem with path in SVG is that path can not have a border, so you can do: a) add more series to render border b) use `renderer.rect()` to draw a border manually, this way you can also remove `addSeries()` as rectangles have fill and border.

Comment: @pawel, perhaps you can post an answer of how I would draw a similar rectangle in the correct spot on the x axis using `renderer.rec`. I am not sure how I would get the correct references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG's path can not have border, so solution is to use `renderer.rect()`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9gqca584/43/

Note: It's `bar` series, so chart is inverted, that means we need to swap x with y and height with width.

Snippet:

```
function addRect(chart) {
  return chart.renderer.rect(
    chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(5) - 4, // 4 = half width
    chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(0),
    8,
    5
  ).attr({
    fill: 'rgba(253,0,154,0.9)',
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    zIndex: 5
  }).add();
}

function positionRect(chart, rect) {
  rect.animate({
    x: chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(5) - 4, // 4 = half width
    y: chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(0) - chart.series[0].points[0].pointWidth / 2,
    height: chart.series[0].points[0].pointWidth
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      events: {
        load: function() {
          this.customRect = addRect(this);
          positionRect(this, this.customRect);
        },
        redraw: function() {
          positionRect(this, this.customRect)
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  });
});
```